# How to deal with random letter upper and lower case instance in db when querying?

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

What is the best way to deal with random upper and lower case letters when querying by string in a database?

Is there some standard way, or should I only allow entries in the database to be all lower case and convert them later?

Right now I have this query in PHP:

```
    $get_category = "select category_name from categories where category_name = ".$some_var;
```

but not sure if its the best way to go when dealing with entries that can be upper or lower case.

I use MySQL.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL is case sensitive or not depending on the collation. Choose a collation that ends with '_ci' (for case insensitive), and queries on that column will use case insensitive comparisation.

Another solution would be to use the `UPPER` function to convert the column and the search value to uppercase, but doing this will cause any indexes on the column not to be used.

Comment: hi, not really familiar with collation.  Is that something that is part of the query?  Or table structure? How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide an example or link for more information on "choose a collation that ends with '_ci'?  My googling hasn't turned up how to do this.

Comment: It's part of the table structure. You can set a collation per database, table or column. You can choose it in PHPMyAdmin, or set it using a DDL statement. Here's a [piece of information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html) about what collation is. And [here's how to set it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-syntax.html).

Comment: The COLLATION can also be specified with LIKE. Not sure about other cases.

Comment: @pst Thank you, [indeed you can](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html). Although the documentation is unclear about the effect on performance (the use of indexes to be more precise). I can imagine that this eliminates the use of indexes, just as `upper` does, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL's default collations are case-insensitive, so 'Hello' and 'HeLLo' are both equal. If  you need to coerce data into a consistent casing, you can use the [`LOWER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) and [`UPPER()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) string functions.

Answer (score 1):

Common pattern is to level the playing field, and make both comparison strings the same case.  For example:

```
$get_category = "select category_name from categories 
    where lower(category_name) = ".strtolower($some_var);
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL supports COLLATION sequences, some of which are case-insensitive. (I do not know what the SQL standard says otherwise, but consult the vendor documentation.)

In this case, see [Case Sensitivity in String Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) from the MySQL manual. Here is a list of the [supported collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html), where `_ci`-postfixed collations are case-insensitive.

Note that, in addition to being specified per table schema, the COLLATION can also be specified for the LIKE operator in a query.

Happy coding.

---

And, please, please, please, *use placeholders* to keep SQL strings tidy and avoid SQL injection attacks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this:

"select category_name from categories where LOWER(category_name) = LOWER(".$some_var.")";

but this could be slow (would be fast if you will store lowercased category_name in database).

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in the past, when I needed to retain the case of the original string (for, say, a login name) is to create another column with the value normalized (all upper or lower case.)  That way, I can perform efficient comparisons by simply converting the string I'm comparing to to the same case.

If performance isn't an issue (as in, not a lot of data) then just applying upper() or lower() to the column in the where clause will do the trick.  But doing so guarantees a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the UPPER sql function to test:

```
$get_category = "select category_name from categories where UPPER(category_name) = UPPER(".$some_var.");
```

But that is really inefficient. A better way would be to store the values as uppercase (or lowercase) from the beginning.

*EDIT*

You should also really consider using parametrized queries instead of simply concatenating the variables into the query. This helps prevent SQL injection attacks!

For instance, you could prepare & execute your query like so:

```
 $preparedStatement = $db->prepare('SELECT category_name FROM categories WHERE UPPER(category_name) = :category');
 $preparedStatement->execute(array(':category' => strtoupper($some_var)));
 $rows = $preparedStatement->fetchAll();
```